# Error <?php echo json_encode($variable) ?> and {{!! json_encode($variable) !!}}

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

I'm using Laravel 5.4 on a small project. I have a controller processing some data, producing an array and storing it on a `$transactions` variable.

When I return the variable from the controller (temporarily and just to check the content, after which I delete that instruction) I use

```
return $transactions;
```

and the result displayed on the browser is:

```
[
    ["Entrada por Ajuste","20170204","2017-02-05","Inventario al 04FEB2017 Pag. 1",7,70,10,70,7],

    ["Venta","20170206","2017-02-06","Ventas del Lunes",1,10,0.8695652173913,60,69]

    ]
```

however when I use the same controller to return the data to a view (with:

```
return view('products.kardex', compact(
            'product', 
            'transactions',
            'beforeCost', 
            'beforeQty')
            );
```

to render the array data in a view with the instruction:

```
var dataSet = {{!! json_encode($transactions) !!}};
```

I get this rendered:

```
var dataSet = {[["Entrada por Ajuste","20170204","2017-02-05","Inventario al 04FEB2017 Pag. 1",7,70,10,70,7],["Venta","20170206","2017-02-06","Ventas del Lunes",1,10,0.8695652173913,60,69]]};
```

adding an extra **{**[[ in the rendered view which is giving me some trouble.

Additionally if I try this in the view:

```
var dataSet = <?php echo json_encode($transactions) ?>;
```

I get this rendered:

```
var dataSet = [["Entrada por Ajuste","20170204","2017-02-05","Inventario al 04FEB2017 Pag. 1",7,70,10,70,7],["Venta","20170206","2017-02-06","Ventas del Lunes",1,10,0.8695652173913,60,69]];
```

Which is what I actually need in the view

My questions is aren't `<?php echo ?>` and `{{!! !!}}` equivalents?. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply do

```
{!! json_encode($transactions) !!}
```

Remove one curly brace '{'